# Darboux Sums of an n-dimensional cube

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, riemann-sum

> The cube $[0, 1]^n$ is admissible, and $v([0, 1]^n ) = 1$. Prove it
>   Using Darboux sums.
>
> Hint: $L_N (\mathbb{1}[0,1]^n ) = 1$  and $U_N (\mathbb{1}[0,1]^n ) =
>  2^{-nN} (2^N + 2)^n$

So I get that using the hint  $U_N (\mathbb{1}[0,1]^n )\rightarrow1$ when $N \rightarrow \infty$ and then $\mathbb{1}[0,1]^n$ is integrable and the cube is admissable and that solves it, however I would love to see a proof of the hint, I think it would help me grasp the concept of darboux sums in n-dimensions better.

Any help?

Comment: What do you take as definition of "admissible" ? I had never heard about that in this context.

Comment: A bounded set $E \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is admissible, if $\mathbb{1}_E$ is integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Darboux upper and lower sums of a function $F: \mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ are defined as follows:

$$L_N (F) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n} 2^{-nN} \inf_{x \in 2^{-N}([0,1]^n + k)} F(x)$$

$$U_N (F) = \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}^n} 2^{-nN} \sup_{x \in 2^{-N}([0,1]^n + k)} F(x)$$

We define: $$F(x) = \begin{cases}
1,  & \text{if $x$ $\in [0,1]^n$} \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

For every $N$, we have exactly $2^{nM}$ cubes that reside within our original cube $[0,1]^n$. Notice that in those cube $inf F=supF=1$.

We also need to consider the cubes outside $[0,1]^n$ that share a common boundary with our original cube. In those cubes, $supF=1$ but $infF =0$.

For example, consider the case where $n=1$, and the interval $I = [1,1+2^{-nM}]$. We get $inf_I F=0$ but $sup_I F=1$.

So $L_N (F)$ is always equal to 1. In order to get $U_N (\mathbb{1}[0,1]^n ) =
 2^{-nN} (2^N + 2)^n$, simply count the amount of $2^{-nM}$ cubes that have a common boundary with the original cube.